# Product sizes showing up in wrong order magento 2

Tags: magento2

my products are showing up in wrong order. I did a migration 1.7 to 2.2.

Hope anyone can tell what i can do.
[image]

Comment: Store >> Attributes >> Product >> Select Size Attributes >> https://www.screencast.com/t/Al9t48rhq7 try this

Comment: Thanks for ya answer! But i think there in the right position:https://www.screencast.com/t/SjYDjgkDD

Comment: Which product type you are using? Configurable or Simple?

Comment: Configurable, i find something:
Some products are fine, and as above isn't, check my screenshot:
https://www.screencast.com/t/NsaqpeotC

BUT! 
Where the red circle is, "Size" and "Maat" are the same, and only "Maat" has to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself, open the product and saved it. Don't know why, but it's working fine now.